# URL Rewrite pattern via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I could need some help on rewriting the patetrn of the following URL

```
/folder/subfolder/Product-Name--1235.html
```

to the URL pattern

```
/p/product-name/1235
```

So, the -- needs to be replaced by a / and then added by the number with unknown length.

Any help / info would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following Redirect :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^folder/subfolder/(.+?)--([0-9]+)\.html$ /p/$1/$2 [L,R]
```

The rule above will redirect any URIs of the form `/folder/subfolder/foobar--123.html` to `/p/foobar/123` .
Just put the rule at the top of your root htaccess file.

Comment: Thank you @Amit Verma, you made my day! That works like a charm :). I guess I was close by trying the reg expression `^(.*)[-]{2}(.*).html`

Question: as there are a lot folders with subfolders where I should then write rules, could I also try to ignore the `/folder/subfolder/`? F.e. like `RewriteRule ^(.+?)--([0-9]+)\.html$ /p/$1/$2 [L,R=301]` which is not working.

Comment: @Bacelo Here is the generic pattern that should work for all folders and subfolders `RewriteRule /([^/]+)--([0-9]+)\.html$ /p/$1/$2 [L,R=301]` . Test this after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Thank you again @Amit Verma - that works perfect! I will look deeper in regex to understand the logic.

Comment: Another question: just found some text pattern in some URLs where I need to add a "-" inbetween some special text part like `/folder/subfolder/ASpecial-Product-Name--1235.html` (before) and `/p/A-Special-Product-Name/1235` after. So this could be - I guess - a seperate RewriteRule afterwards like `(.*)ASpecial(.*)` to `(.*)A-Special(.*)`.